# Save iteration's result from Markov Chain Python

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, markov-chains

In the context of Natural language Generation (NLG), I want to generate 300 sentences with Python's library "Markovify" base on the principle of Makov Chain. 
My input file which containing text is "SD".

First, I was able to print all the iteration's (=300) results (texts) with the following code :

```
import markovify
text_model = markovify.NewlineText(SG.Text, state_size = 1)

  for i in range(300): # Generate 300 sentences 
            result = [] 
            result.append(text_model.make_sentence())
            print(result)
```

Then, I would like to obtain a list of all theses iteration result in one list so I tried :

```
def f(i,result):
    for i in range(300): # Generate 300 sentences 
        result = [] 
        result.append(text_model.make_sentence())
    return result
```

But I only get a list with the result of the last iteration.
What can I modify in my code to obtain a list containing all the iteration result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `result = []` must be before the for loop, or you initialise it every iteration:

```
def f():
    result = [] 
    for i in range(300): # Generate 300 sentences 
        result.append(text_model.make_sentence())
    return result

sentences = f()
print(sentences)
```

Edit: You don't actually need to give `result` and `i` as arguments.

Even better would be comprehension:

```
def f():
    return [text_model.make_sentence() for _ in range(300)]
```

Comment: I've already tried that, and in this case, I've just obtained an empty list as result

Comment: Strange ... I updated my code a bit ... Is it still not working like this? If I replace `text_model.make_sentence()` (because I don't have your function) with `"kjsdksj"`, it works for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, my code is working with your solution (I use the first solution with sentences list) 